# Automatically resize windows to fit display when dragged to smaller display in Gnome?

Tags: gnome

#### Context

I use multiple monitors, and one is smaller than the others (the laptop's built in display).

#### Problem

I often have windows on the larger display that are larger than the small display. When I drag such windows to the smaller display, they don't fit.

##### Existing solutions / Workarounds

- **Manual resize**: After dragging a large window to a small display, the top of the window is on-screen (since that was the dragging handle) but the bottom is not, so I have to...

  1. Resize it down (i.e., drag down the top of the window); most of the window is still off-screen. So, then...
  2. Drag the window up so it's back on-screen.
  3. I then often also resize the window again to the desired size now that it's all on-screen.
- **Move window one monitor to the left/right** Navigation Keyboard Shortcut: Gnome won't move the window to the smaller display if it's too big for that display (making this not applicable to the problem).
- **Snapping/Maximizing** The window can be automatically resized to fit using Active Screen Edges, or the "View split on left/right" keyboard shortcuts, which snaps the window to the left or right side, or maximized. However, I would like the window resized but not in one of these states (snapped or maximized). If I first put the window in one of these states before moving it to the small display, then "Restore" it out of a snap (drag from snap, or use the 'Restore window' shortcut), then the window returns to being too big for the display.

#### Question

Is there a way to have Gnome automatically resize a window to fit the display when dragged onto a smaller display (excluding using Snapping), like some command-line based setting? Or at least an easy way (e.g., keyboard shortcut) to trigger a resize-to-fit?